# Sum of the first $1/n$-th powers of z, L-function with rational powers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, special-functions, l-functions

The sum of the first $n$-th roots of some given complex number $z$ in the unit open disk, $|z|<1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^N z^{1/n},$$
could be expressed as a polynomial series on $N$ or $z$, or it might exist a generating function or $L$-function with rational powers related.

Morever, some sort of $L$-function should have the form
$$L(z,s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{1/n}}{n^s}.$$

Any ideas/references?

Comment: Since this isn’t a function which can be made entire on $\mathbb C,$ I doubt you can find a polynomial in $z.$

Comment: I doubt also that this is a (finite-degree) polynomial, although It can be regarded as a polynomial with rational powers. The Taylor series of the $n$-th root could be used, but I neither find the general formula for the $n$-th root.

Comment: Polynomials are finite degree, by definition. No reason to specify that.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: There are two questions:
1) How to calculate the sum of the $N$ first $n$-th roots of a given number $Z$ (strictly not the $n$-th root, but the fractional power $z^{1/n}$), as written in the first formula.

2) Is there an already-studied L-function such as the second formula?